# bash: autogen.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I try to install opensmile 3.0 in Raspberry Pi
terminal steps in below:

```
$sudo apt-get install autoconf
$sudo apt-get install libtool
$sudo apt-get install m4
$sudo apt-get install gcc

$ cd Desktop
$ cd opensmile 3.0
$ bash autogen.sh
```

It says that
`bash: autogen.sh: No such file or directory`

I find that some people say that it may due to a missing file and I try
`apt-get install ia32-libs`
How can I do to install opensmile 3.0?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Where did you get these commands?

Comment: Have you read https://audeering.github.io/opensmile/get-started.html ?